# Facing XSS issue in Liferay 7.1.1 GA2

Tags: security, liferay, liferay-7

We have Liferay site that is ready to move into production. We ran a Vulnerability scan on the site recently and faced XSS issues which we need to solve before going LIVE.

Liferay is allowing the request like below,

```
https://<domain>/categories/sample/category/<script>xss</script> 
https://<domain>/categories/sample/category/<script>alert("Script Executed")</script>
```

Above URL is being allowed in Liferay which needs to be validated, it will be helpful if anyone can guide me on how to validate this or prevent these requests.  We are holding up our release due to this issue, any guidance will be greatly helpful.

```
Versions used:
Liferay : 7.1.1 GA2(Bundled version)
Tomacat: 9.0.10
```

I tried below options but that din't help in portal-ext.properties as well but that din't help:

```
xss.allow=false
xss.allow.com.liferay.portal.model.Portlet=false
xss.allow.com.liferay.portal.model.PortletPreferences=false
xss.allow.com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle.content=false
xss.allow.com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalStructure.xsd=false
xss.allow.com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalTemplate.xsl=false
```

I can see that some of the fix was already done in Liferay in older versions but still am facing it in 7.1.1,
Links of the fixes:
[Link1](https://issues.liferay.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/LEP-5921)
[Link2](https://web.liferay.com/community/security-team/known-vulnerabilities/-/asset_publisher/T8Ei/content/cst-sa-lps-45661-various-xss-issues-in-6-2-1?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.liferay.com%2Fcommunity%2Fsecurity-team%2Fknown-vulnerabilities%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_T8Ei%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-5%26p_p_col_count%3D1)

Comment: I could not reproduce this on Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.1.1 CE GA2, is there custom code involved ? maybe a theme... the URL is not found

Comment: Answered on [your crosspost](https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/114795574). Please [read this question and its answers about crossposting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823)

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue by having a filter which will validate the url , You can refer the link for using filter https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-1/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/servlet-filters You can refer below link for raising issue https://portal.liferay.dev/participate/feedback/report-issues